# apt-cache show: Can't select versions from package as it is purely virtual

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I was messing around with postgresql packages in Ubuntu:

```
$ apt-cache show postgresql
$ apt-cache show postgresql-10
$ apt-cache show postgresql-contrib
```

when:

```
$ apt-cache show postgresql-contrib-10
N: Can't select versions from package 'postgresql-contrib-10' as it is purely virtual
N: No packages found
```

Someone knows what that 'purely virtual' means?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`postgresql-contrib-10` is provided by the main `postgres-10` package (thus, virtual). In older versions this was a separate package that now seems to be functionally merged into the main package, as far as I understand it.

```
$ apt-cache show postgresql-10|grep Provides
Provides: postgresql-contrib-10
```